# Using v.clean crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, v.clean

I am working on a shapefile depicting English administrative divisions in QGIS 3.16.15. I began first by using the 'Fix geometries' tool to remove invalid geometries. Then, I used the topology editor to identity several thousand gaps and overlaps between the polygons. I am trying to fix these geometries using v.clean, but no matter what option I select, I continuously get the same string of errors in the log.

[image]

[image]

Then, the program crashes.

Comment: Can you share the shapefile?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0hdgrhashddyj3/Hundreds.zip?dl=0

The dataset is the same one as this one from here, except I have fixed invalid geometries: https://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/catalogue/adsdata/arch-3676-1/dissemination/DBhundreds.zip

Comment: Excepting the crash I just had this with a complex layer I had been given.  It had lots of slivers, some overlaps, and many multiparts but valid geometry.  I ended up converting it to singleparts, recalculating areas, then selecting for those under a size and running the eliminate tool.  Looked good but it generated a few collect geometries, I think in the overlap polys locations which I couldn't get rid of.  So I actually used the old convert to coverage and back at that point.  Finally I ran the v.clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know why your attempt does not work. But you should be able to fix it with a more manual approach:

Fix the holes:

1. Dissolve
2. Delete holes
3. Difference with your start layer as input layer, and dissolved layer as overlay. Now you have the holes as small polygons
4. Merge these with the input layer
5. Select them by area and Eliminate

Self intersections:

1. Union the output from above with itself (can take some time)
2. Select the overlaps with "TerrID"<>"TerrID_2"
3. Eliminate them

Then delete the extra fields created in the Union with Refactor fields (or do it manually)

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant for getting rid of the holes, thank you for your help.

However, the overlaps still remain even after trying your method. Though the Union tool allows me to select the overlaps by expression, the Eliminate tool doesn't seem to erase them. Do you know if there is anything else I could perhaps try?

Comment: Nice! How do you check that the overlaps remain?

Comment: I used topology checker with the rule ‘must not have overlaps’ on the layer produced by the eliminate tool. It returned a few hundred overlaps. I zoomed into a couple of the errors and saw that they remain. Still, removing the holes was a great help towards cleaning up this shapefile!